# PHP !is_resource($RS) vs ($RS === false) vs !$RS

Tags: php

When checking for a valid resource in PHP, I'm wondering if these are interchangeable. The first two methods are being used where I work and as far as I can tell they are accomplishing the same thing.

Edit: When I first asked this question I was using some code copied from the PHP manual for my example, which contained mysql commands. Since I'm not using mysql I decided it would be better to rewrite the question.

Method 1 - use !is_resource, which has a little more overhead than a direct comparison such as in method 2

```
$RS = sqlsrv_query($con, $SQL);
if (!is_resource($RS)) {
    die('not a resource');
}
```

Method 2 - a direct comparison

```
$RS = sqlsrv_query($con, $SQL);
if ($RS === false) {
    die('not a resource');
}
```

Method 3 - is this the same as method 2, just less wordy? Or is there some nuance with the === that I'm missing?

```
$RS = sqlsrv_query($con, $SQL);
if (!$RS) {
    die('not a resource');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should stop using the `mysql` extension, it has been obsolete for years and has been removed from the current version of PHP.

Comment: They're all equivalent. `mysql_connect()` returns either a resource or false. A resource is always truthy. The choice of which to use is just personal style.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect will only return either a resource, or false.

Effectively, `!$db_link` and `$db_link === false` are the same. Edit: "in this instance." They aren't actually the same, as === performs strict type checking, but for the purposes of this discussion, they are effectively the same.

`is_resource` is effectively the same as well, just slightly more overhead but not enough to be concerned for such a micro-optimization.

You should not be writing new code using `mysql_` functions. It has been deprecated for a very long time. The replacement was `mysqli_`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what possible values you're dealing with, and these values can clearly be distinguished by a simple boolean test, then that is perfectly fine enough. `mysql_connect` returns either a resource or a boolean `false`. The boolean `false` will always be *falsey* and the resource will always be *truthy*, hence `if (!$db_link)` is a perfectly adequate and concise test. There is no case in which this would fail given the two possible values that `$db_link` can be here.

`=== false` is more explicit about the boolean comparison, but unnecessarily so. It doesn't add anything, except verbosity.

`is_resource` also works for your purpose and is more explicit the other way, but again unnecessarily so. It won't match any additional case a simple boolean comparison wouldn't here.